# Generate sitemap XML file from sql database?

Tags: c#, sql, xml

Hi I would like to generate site map xml from my database. So far from my research I have found that

1.Generating it with c# code and writing dataset in to xml format

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/8115/generating-xml-file-from-sql-database-using-c-sharp.aspx

1. Second procedure is directly writing data into xml format from database.

Can you guys tell me which is the best way and my database is huge. And i want my xml to look like this

```
<url>
<location>http://xxx.com/default.aspx?page=PageID</location>
<title>xxxxxxxx</title>
<lastmodified>01-01-1900</lastmodified>
</url>
```

PageID, page title and date will come from database tables.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You don´t provide info about your database access strategy or technology so, I assume you are using some kind of ORM which support Linq. If that's right you can do it as follow:

```
var siteMapBody = 
from page in DataContext.Pages
        select new XElement(XName.Get("url"),
               new XElement(XName.Get("location"), page.Url),
               new XElement(XName.Get("title"), page.Title),
               new XElement(XName.Get("lastmodified"), page.LastModified));

var siteMapDocument = new XDocument(siteMapBody);
var siteMap = siteMapDocument.ToString();
```

Good luck!